# Can I ever play Undertale again normally?

Tags: undertale

The ending I got is :

> the genocide

When I reset my file, my past choices still take effect. I want to start a clean run.

I don't want to buy the game again, what do I do?

Comment: You do not need to buy the game again.  Doing so probably won't help as it may still see the original save data.

Answer (score 31):

If you're running the Steam version of the game, deleting files in the save directory won't be enough. Steam Cloud will automatically restore those files, and it also keeps a local cache of the files to restore them even if you're offline. While it's possible to clear these files out, it's complicated, and a simpler solution exists on Windows if you have sufficient access rights on your computer.

- Go to your computer's save location. (Default on Windows: [User folder]\AppData\Local\UNDERTALE)
- Right click the file system_information_962 or system_information_963, depending on if you are on post-genocide black screen, or post-genocide post-soul-sold.
- Go into properties, then security. Remove [Your username] and [administrators] rights to READ the file. Click apply.
- When you next start up the game, it will be as if you had never done a genocide run ever before.

If you're not playing the Steam version of the game, the simplest method to remove the consequences of completing a genocide run is to fully uninstall and reinstall the game.

Source: http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Genocide_Route#Consequence_Avoidance

Comment: Just to note, as of today when i checked your source link, there's a tumblr link that provides an executable that can do the same thing.  You may already know this (Mike), but I wanted to point that out to anyone else trying to fix this problem who doesn't feel comfortable going through those steps.

Comment: Would disabling Steam Cloud Saving (which is an option buried in the game properties) BEFORE completing the genocide run also work? (Assuming the files are manually deleted after the run...)

Comment: @dakre18 I'd personally trust something I did myself over a strange third-party tool, but I'm tech-savvy. =P Looks like someone else already posted an answer about the tool, though.

Comment: @Shaamaan Afraid I don't know. Seems like it would, but that might be something worth making a new question about.

Comment: I'm the same way Michael, but I tend to use tools like that when i feel lazy or have to do it multiple times.

Answer (score 7):

If you find where the Undertale save files are located, you can delete them and start fresh. According to [this Steam forum post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/391540/discussions/0/523897653297877673/), the save files are in appdata\local\UNDERTALE on Windows, ~/Library/Application Support/com.tobyfox.undertale/ on Mac. There is also a save manager available which one of my friends has used successfully, but since it's a third party program use it at your own risk: [Undertale Save Manager](http://lycaon.me/undertale.html).

Keep in mind that if you're playing Undertale through Steam, the Steam Cloud saves may attempt to overwrite your save file with the stored version when you try to remove it. Disable it to prevent this from happening.

Comment: You will also need to turn off steam cloud saves if you're using the steam version, otherwise it will "helpfully" redownload them after you delete them.

Comment: That's correct, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to clean everything up (including your Steam cloud) would be to use UGR ([Undertale Genocide Remover](https://fucknohtml.tumblr.com/post/133037946850/do-you-own-the-steam-version-of-undertale-do-you)). This is a third-party and, as usual, you should be careful with those. (I personally already used it and it worked fine with no apparent viruses.)

But don't think that ***YOU*** will have a clean conscience though. The app make sure to give you chills ;)

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 3):

If not a steam downloaded version just go to ~/Library/Application Support/com.tobyfox.u and delete all files. Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

[From the Undertale Wiki](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Genocide_Route#Consequence_Avoidance)

> **Save Locations**
>
> Default save locations are as follows:
>
> - *Windows:*   * *Windows XP:* %SystemDrive%/Documents and Settings/%USERNAME%/Local/Application Data/UNDERTALE   * *Windows
>     Vista/7/8/10:* %LOCALAPPDATA%/UNDERTALE
> - *Linux:*   * *DRM-free:* ~/.config/UNDERTALE_linux   * *Steam:* ~/.config/UNDERTALE_linux_steamver
> - *Mac:* ~/Library/Application Support/com.tobyfox.undertale/
>
> **Modifying/Deleting Files**
>
> To return to a playable state, the player can enter their save data
>   folder and either:
>
> - Delete the last directory in the aforementioned save location for your respective system; this removes everything you have done in the
>     game as if it is your first time playing it
> - Delete or rename the files `system_information_962` and `system_information_963` in the aforementioned save
>     location. This removes any effects of having done the Genocide Route.
>     The `system_information_962` file is the one that you have
>     erased the world, and `system_information_963` is when you
>     have sold your soul.
> - Uninstall the game and do a fresh reinstall. GOG players using GOG Galaxy may need to disable cloud saving before carrying out any of
>     these steps. Also, these methods are not sufficient for players of the
>     Steam version, as the Steam Cloud backs up the acquisition of the
>     system_information files and restores them if deleted (even if cloud
>     synchronization is disabled). Players of the Steam version have to
>     delete their Steam Cloud cache as stated
>     [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2470784),
>     or render the system_information files unreadable by ''Undertale'' by
>     modifying their security settings under file properties to deny read
>     permission.
> - The [Undertale Genocide Remover](http://fucknohtml.tumblr.com/post/133037946850/do-you-own-the-steam-version-of-undertale-do-you)
>     application automatically removes all Genocide Route files, even those
>     in Steam, when "ERASE" is pressed.

Answer (score -3):

Easy, reset regularly and do the true pacifist route, the choice you make about giving chara your soul or not to restore the world is the only thing that will twist the story, the twist you should find yourself

Comment: OP specifically mentions he doesn't want those changes to happen anymore. He wants to play the game as if it's his first playthrough.

Comment: oh, crap, my bad