# Can I get dunked on again?

Tags: pc, cheats, undertale

I just beat undertale on genocide route for the first time. One of the bosses was really *fun* to fight. In particular, I really liked fighting the boss

> Sans.

I'm a homicidal maniac who enjoys killing innocent monsters, so I'd like to fight him again. Is there anyway I can re-fight him without redoing the entire genocide run? Obviously, this would require hacking save files. Can I manually modify my existing save files, or would I have to download the a save file specifically for the location I fight him in?

Comment: Um... You can look in your save files in `%APPDATA%/local/undertale/save9`.        (Remember save9 is a file with no extension. Open using notepad.)

Comment: @Alex That file doesn't show up. In that same folder, I only have `config.ini`, `playerachievementcache.dat` (empty) and `system_information_962`

Comment: hmm... Try seeing if it's a hidden file.

Comment: @Alex It's not. Right now, I have no save files since [spoiler!] Chara erased the world.

Comment: I haven't done genocide yet..... Can't help you there.

Comment: "that look... that's the look of someone who's died three times in a row. i must be really good at my job, huh?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You're better off just downloading one

While it's theoretically possible to edit a save file (which is apparently actually split over 4 different files), it would require someone to do a lot of research on every possible variable inside the files, and might be further complicated by the presence of validation checks inside the save data. This may or may not already be done by someone, but even if it is, it would likely still be an arduous task setting all the flags exactly how you want them.

Instead, you'll probably have better luck finding one uploaded online for the particular part of the game you want, especially such a significant point as requested in the question. [This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Undertale/comments/3szvui/my_undertale_save_files/) offers many save files from multiple points throughout the game, on both the Pacifist and Genocide routes, along with instructions on how to customize your name and Spare color.

---

From the comments on your question, it also sounds like you're currently at the point in the game just after

> Chara destroys the world at the end of a Genocide run.

Simply wait for a few minutes on the black screen that appears when you load the game until you're given an option to restore your ability to play the game again. Alternately, avoiding the consequences of a Genocide run entirely, which would also get you out of that state, is described in the question [Can I ever play Undertale again normally?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241785/can-i-ever-play-undertale-again-normally?rq=1)

Comment: Yeah, you're right about where I am right now. I know how to get the game back, I just haven't gotten around to restoring the world yet. Thanks for that reddit link! That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a within-the-game answer, not even a mess-with-game-files answer, this is further out than that, but there is a browser version of just the fight in question, at https://jcw87.github.io/c2-sans-fight/