# Unkill Mettaton Neo Undertale Genocide

Tags: undertale

I killed mettaton neo when I hadn't gotten the required kills for Hotland... and I saved it how do I  de kill her? I tried the time-travel thing and it did not work.

Comment: You can't once you sqved

Comment: mettaton is technically male

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Undertale, you only have one save slot in-game.  **Once you've saved, your only option is to reset to start from the beginning again.**

That being said, parts of the game is recorded in hidden locations of your PC. Here's a link to answers as to [how to completely "reset" your Undertale save as if you're playing for the first time again](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241785/can-i-ever-play-undertale-again-normally?rq=1). Some of the possible options are also to use 3rd-party programs that will allow you to save/restore the game in different states. *(Use at your own risk of course.)*

As for "unkilling", the path you've taken is already set. You cannot go back. Your only option is to reset and try again. (*...assuming you really want to have a bad time.*)

Comment: "because if you take one more step, you are ***REALLY*** not going to like what happens next.."